# Passing variables from JavaScript to HTML and HTML button inputs to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I am trying to make a simple game using JavaScript and HTML.

The game consists of having two buttons on the screen with random numbers and clicking the one that is smaller.

At the end, you will get your results.

What I am having trouble with is getting the random number generated in JavaScript to print on the button and getting the data back to JavaScript from the button.

```js
var number = prompt('Choose Your Difficulty, Easy, Normal, Or Hard?');
var number = number.toUpperCase(); //Chooses difficulty


if (number === 'EASY')//easy difficulty
{
 var difficulty = 20;
}else if (number === 'NORMAL')//normal difficulty
{
 var difficulty = 100;
}else if(number === 'HARD')//hard difficulty
{
 var difficulty = 1000;
}else
{
  alert('Please Enter A Valid Answer')//if value is not valid
}

var number1 = Math.floor((Math.random()* difficulty) + 1);//random number 1 

var number2 = Math.floor((Math.random()* difficulty) + 1);//random number 2

//----------------------Code i found but im not sure now to use it--------------

// 1. Create the button
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "Do Something";

// 2. Append somewhere
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button);

// 3. Add event handler
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
   alert("did something");
});

 //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```css
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 40px;
  background: salmon;
  border: none;
}
button:hover {
  background: lightsalmon;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Speed Game
    </title>
    
      <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css">
    
     <script src="../script/script.js"></script>
  </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <button id= "button">
  Do Something!
</button>
      
    </body>
  </html>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, welcome to the world of programming!

Second, here's the game you wanted. I've done everything using functions, so understanding it should be easy.

Try to play a few games first!

The concept is pretty simple, really, so after playing a bit, look at the code and try to figure it out on your own!

```js
var number;
var difficulty = 0;

var randomNumOne; 
var randomNumTwo;

var buttonOne = document.getElementById("buttonOne");
var buttonTwo = document.getElementById("buttonTwo");

var tempButton;


function requestDifficulty(){
  number = prompt('Choose Your Difficulty, Easy, Normal, Or Hard?');
  number = number.toUpperCase(); 
  setDifficulty();
}

function setDifficulty(){
  if (number === 'EASY'){
    difficulty = 20;
    startGame();
  }else if (number === 'NORMAL'){
    difficulty = 100;
    startGame();
  }else if(number === 'HARD'){
    difficulty = 1000;
    startGame();
  }else{
  alert('Please Enter A Valid Answer');
    requestDifficulty()
  }
}
function startGame(){
  randomNumOne = Math.floor((Math.random()* difficulty) + 1); 
  randomNumTwo = Math.floor((Math.random()* difficulty) + 1);
  buttonOne.innerHTML = randomNumOne;
  buttonTwo.innerHTML = randomNumTwo;
}

function getResults(pressedButton){
  tempButton = pressedButton;
  if(tempButton == "buttonOne"){
    if(randomNumOne < randomNumTwo){
      alert("Correct!")
    }else{
      alert("False!")
    }
  }else if(tempButton == "buttonTwo"){
    if(randomNumTwo < randomNumOne){
      alert("Correct!")
    }else{
      alert("False!")
    }
  }
  
}

requestDifficulty();
```

```css
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 40px;
  background: salmon;
  border: none;
}
button:hover {
  background: lightsalmon;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      Speed Game
    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <button id="buttonOne" onclick="getResults('buttonOne');">
        random number 1
      </button>
      <button id="buttonTwo" onclick="getResults('buttonTwo')">
        random number 2
      </button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! i understand the code now and it works fine on here but when i try to use it outside of here the buttons work but they do not display the number, they display "random number 1" and "random number 2". i understand that these 2 lines of code buttonOne.innerHTML = randomNumOne; buttonTwo.innerHTML = randomNumTwo; Should fix that problem but i cant figure out why they do no

Comment: Did you copy all of the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript correctly? Here, go to https://jsbin.com and Paste the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript into their correct places and press the "Run with JS" button at the top-right corner of the result window. The buttons only display "random number 1"  and "random number 2" before the `alert` asks you to input the difficulty. After that, the random numbers will be printed instead of these sentences.

Comment: Through that program i downloaded the code and it put it all in the same file as the html and it all works now, i never thought having the files separated would make the code not work. But thank you so much i have had this problem for ever and i cant thank you enough!

Comment: You're welcome, friend! But as a note, If you want to put the files separated, you have to put the link to the CSS file in the `<head>` tag at the beginning of your HTML, and then, you _have_ to put the link to your JavaScript file at the _end_ of the `<body>` tag. Not _after_ the `<body>` tag, but at the _end_ of it, inside it. It should work! If you place the link to your JavaScript file at the beginning of the `<body>` tag or at the `<head>` tag, it will not work!